# How to make a NSStream socket connection to a HTTP_PROXY server (server also requires authentication)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I know how to create input/ output stream sockets using `NSStream` class. I was able to make a TCP connection and SSL connection also. But I don't know how can I make a stream socket connection to a `HTTP_PROXY` Server. Server also requires sending the Username/ password.

Is this possible using `NSStream` API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who is stuck like me. This is how I solved it.

- Use CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest rather than
  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost.
- Use the correct proxy keys - `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost` and
  `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort`.

  ```
     CFHTTPMessageRef    request;

     request = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(
         NULL, 
         CFSTR("GET"), 
         (__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"], 
         kCFHTTPVersion1_1
     );
     assert(request != NULL);

     self.inputStream = CFBridgingRelease( 
         CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(NULL, request)
     );

     CFRelease(request);

     if (YES) {
         BOOL            success;
         NSDictionary *  proxyDict;

         proxyDict = @{
             (__bridge NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost: @"proxy.example.com",
             (__bridge NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort: @12345,
         };

         success = [self.inputStream setProperty:proxyDict 
             forKey:(__bridge NSString *) kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy
         ];
         assert(success);
     }

     [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
     [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
         forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
     ];
     [self.inputStream open];
  ```